# how to groupby by date and custom range of time pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a table like this:

```
          value   time         date         
0           1   06:30:04    2021-01-01
1           1   07:02:37    2021-01-01
2           1   08:22:45    2021-01-01
3           1   08:33:39    2021-01-01
4           1   09:02:41    2021-01-01
```

I want to group by the date but in custom range. if the time is exactly after 12:30:00 p.m., I want to count that as the next day. or in other words, the wanted range starts from 12:31 p.m. to 12:30 p.m. of day after. for example, if the date is 2021-01-01 and the time is 12:30:01 p.m. the row goes to the 2021-01-02 element. how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a [datetime rounding function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.round.html), which you could use to round to the day.  Here I've edited your last record to occur after 12:30

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 'time': ['06:30:04', '07:02:37', '08:22:45', '08:33:39', '12:45:41'],
 'date': ['2021-01-01',
  '2021-01-01',
  '2021-01-01',
  '2021-01-01',
  '2021-01-01']})

output = df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time']).round('D'))['value'].sum().reset_index()
```

Output

```
       index  value
0 2021-01-01      4
1 2021-01-02      1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but I have another problem now!! this is the problem:"unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and 'str' "

Comment: perhaps `df['date'] = df['date'].astype(str)` before the groupby since it sounds like your date is already a datetime object

Comment: @MohmmadHadi I'd encourage you to use pandas date and time objects (as opposed to datetime module) when using pandas.  Calculations will be much more efficient, it exposes much more functionality and will be less error prone.

Comment: I tried your solution but I didn't get the right answer! I edited my question once more... could you check it out and help me??